# How to create a custom Login Button for facebook login in Android app?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I have already implemented fb login using Facebook's custom Login Button(`com.facebook.widget.LoginButton`).

Now i want to open Facebook login dialog on a custom button click. Is it possible to do so? Or, do i need everytime need to implement Fb `LoginButton`?

As far as the Facebook SDK 3.0 documentation suggests, it always opens up the dialog on its own `LoginButton`, which is quite weird.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Comment: I think you need to use WebView..

Comment: i want to avoid using webview. I have seen apps which opens login dialog on a button click. Need to know did they implement it?

Comment: Thanx coding crow. will keep those in mind.